# Booting with Ubuntu CD on Windows XP sp2 - says isn't supported

Tags: live-usb

I'm trying to use a Ubuntu 12.4 cd on a Dell Latitude D600, Windows XP SP2 512KB Ram
Msg says "This kernel requires the following features no present on the CPU: pae Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU."

I am only trying to boot with the Ubuntu CD so I can access a Buffalo NAS drive to try and get the info off the raid array.
My goal is not to isntall the os, just to get the data off.
I thought there was a notice stating the need for SP3, but can't locate it now.

I am extremely NEW to Linux type products.
Your assistance would be very helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: What processor are you using *(Intel or AMD, 32bit or 64bit etc)*? You may just need to download the appropriate image from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop or http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/

Comment: Your system is so ancient it is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try 32 bit Lubuntu 12.04.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE

Lubuntu and Xubuntu offered a PAE and a non-PAE release up to and including 12.04, but from 12.10 only the PAE releases are maintained.